# Check if the given string follows the given pattern

Tags: string, algorithm, dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm

A friend of mine just had his interview at Google and got rejected because he couldn't give a solution to this question.

I have my own interview in a couple of days and can't seem to figure out a way to solve it.

Here's the question:

> You are given a pattern, such as [a b a b]. You are also given a
> string, example "redblueredblue". I need to write a program that tells
> whether the string follows the given pattern or not.
>
> A few examples:
>
> Pattern: [a b b a] String: catdogdogcat returns 1
>
> Pattern: [a b a b] String: redblueredblue returns 1
>
> Pattern: [a b b a] String: redblueredblue returns 0

I thought of a few approaches, like getting the number of unique characters in the pattern and then finding that many unique substrings of the string then comparing with the pattern using a hashmap. However, that turns out to be a problem if the substring of a is a part of b.

It'd be really great if any of you could help me out with it. :)

UPDATE:

Added Info: There can be any number of characters in the pattern (a-z). Two characters won't represent the same substring. Also, a character can't represent an empty string.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the pattern? Is it just the combinations of symbols in any order?

Comment: Can any of the strings that match a particular letter in the pattern be empty?

Comment: Also, how many possible characters are in the pattern string? Is it always a and b, or can there be more characters?

Comment: There can be any number of characters in the patters. Two characters won't represent the same substring. Also, a character can't represent an empty string.

Comment: There's a naive solution that works by enumerating all partitions of the string into substrings and checking that it matches the pattern string, but that might take time exponential in the length of the pattern string. I'm curious if there is a fundamentally faster approach, or if this is known to be NP-complete (or co-NP-complete?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't you just need to translate the pattern to a regexp using backreferences, i.e. something like this (Python 3 with the "re" module loaded):

```
>>> print(re.match('(.+)(.+)\\2\\1', 'catdogdogcat'))
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 12), match='catdogdogcat'>

>>> print(re.match('(.+)(.+)\\1\\2', 'redblueredblue'))
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 14), match='redblueredblue'>

>>> print(re.match('(.+)(.+)\\2\\1', 'redblueredblue'))
None
```

The regexp looks pretty trivial to generate.  If you need to support more than 9 backrefs, you can use named groups - see the [Python regexp docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html).

Comment: What's the time complexity of this solution? I'm concerned that this would work, but potentially be no faster than a brute-force approach.

Comment: What if I want the 2 name groups to have unique values as their strings?

Comment: @EricM, if regexp is not allowed, what would be the approach?

Comment: @TimothyHa, implement a depth first search like this rough solution: https://gist.github.com/EricMountain/51cb333297ef37230582.

Comment: tried running above gist link and it seems to give incorrect output for some cases.  here is my answer inspired by yours:  https://gist.github.com/alexsapps/83e0054672973672f39e

Comment: Wow, don't know how I managed to push a version that doesn't even compile.  So fixed it to also work with your test cases: https://gist.github.com/EricMountain/51cb333297ef37230582.

Answer (score 19):

The simplest solution that I can think of is to divide the given string into four parts and compare the individual parts. You don't know how long `a` or `b` is, but both `a`s are of the same length as well as `b`s are. So the number of ways how to divide the given string is not very large.

Example:
pattern = `[a b a b]`, given string = `redblueredblue` (14 characters in total)

1. `|a|` (length of `a`) = 1, then that makes 2 characters for `a`s and 12 characters is left for `b`s, i.e. `|b|` = 6. Divided string = `r edblue r edblue`. Whoa, this matches right away!
2. (just out of curiosity) `|a| = 2, |b| = 5` -> divided string = `re dblue re dblue` -> match

Example 2:
pattern = `[a b a b]`, string = `redbluebluered` (14 characters in total)

1. `|a| = 1, |b| = 6` -> divided string = `r edblue b luered` -> no match
2. `|a| = 2, |b| = 5` -> divided string = `re dblue bl uered` -> no match
3. `|a| = 3, |b| = 4` -> divided string = `red blue blu ered` -> no match

The rest is not needed to be checked because if you switched `a` for `b` and vice versa, the situation is identical.

What is the pattern that has [a b c a b c] ?

Comment: But would it work for a pattern like `[a a b b]` or `[b b a a]` ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is java backtracking solution. [Source link](https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/26161/pattern-matching/2).

```
public class Solution {

public boolean isMatch(String str, String pat) {
Map<Character, String> map = new HashMap<>();
return isMatch(str, 0, pat, 0, map);
 }

boolean isMatch(String str, int i, String pat, int j, Map<Character,  String> map) {
// base case
if (i == str.length() && j == pat.length()) return true;
if (i == str.length() || j == pat.length()) return false;

// get current pattern character
char c = pat.charAt(j);

// if the pattern character exists
if (map.containsKey(c)) {
  String s = map.get(c);

  // then check if we can use it to match str[i...i+s.length()]
  if (i + s.length() > str.length() || !str.substring(i, i + s.length()).equals(s)) {
    return false;
  }

  // if it can match, great, continue to match the rest
  return isMatch(str, i + s.length(), pat, j + 1, map);
}

// pattern character does not exist in the map
for (int k = i; k < str.length(); k++) {
  // create or update the map
  map.put(c, str.substring(i, k + 1));

  // continue to match the rest
  if (isMatch(str, k + 1, pat, j + 1, map)) {
    return true;
  }
}

// we've tried our best but still no luck
map.remove(c);

return false;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

One more brute force recursion solution:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int res;
        res = wordpattern("abba", "redbluebluered");
        System.out.println("RESULT: " + res);
    }

    static int wordpattern(String pattern, String input) {
        int patternSize = 1;
        boolean res = findPattern(pattern, input, new HashMap<Character, String>(), patternSize);
        while (!res && patternSize < input.length())
        {
            patternSize++;
            res = findPattern(pattern, input, new HashMap<Character, String>(), patternSize);
        }
        return res ? 1 : 0;
    }

    private static boolean findPattern(String pattern, String input, Map<Character, String> charToValue, int patternSize) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length(); i++) {
            char c = pattern.charAt(i);
            if (charToValue.containsKey(c)) {
                sb.append(charToValue.get(c));
            } else {
                // new character in pattern
                if (sb.length() + patternSize > input.length()) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    String substring = input.substring(sb.length(), sb.length() + patternSize);
                    charToValue.put(c, substring);
                    int newPatternSize = 1;
                    boolean res = findPattern(pattern, input, new HashMap<>(charToValue), newPatternSize);
                    while (!res && newPatternSize + sb.length() + substring.length() < input.length() - 1) {
                        newPatternSize++;
                        res = findPattern(pattern, input, new HashMap<>(charToValue), newPatternSize);
                    }
                    return res;
                }
            }
        }
        return sb.toString().equals(input) && allValuesUniq(charToValue.values());
    }

    private static boolean allValuesUniq(Collection<String> values) {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        for (String v : values) {
            if (!set.add(v)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My Implementation on C#. Tried to look for something clean in C#, couldn't find. So I'll add it to here.

```
   private static bool CheckIfStringFollowOrder(string text, string subString)
    {
        int subStringLength = subString.Length;

        if (text.Length < subStringLength) return false;

        char x, y;
        int indexX, indexY;

        for (int i=0; i < subStringLength -1; i++)
        {
            indexX = -1;
            indexY = -1;

            x = subString[i];
            y = subString[i + 1];

            indexX = text.LastIndexOf(x);
            indexY = text.IndexOf(y);

            if (y < x || indexX == -1 || indexY == -1)
                return false;
        }

        return true;

    }
```

Comment: Looks like you are implementing something completely different.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this as a language production problem using regexen.

```
def  wordpattern( pattern,  string):
    '''
        input: pattern 'abba'
        string  'redbluebluered'
        output: 1 for match, 2 for no match
    '''

    # assemble regex into something like this for 'abba':
    # '^(?P<A>.+)(?P<B>.+)(?P=B)(?P=A)$'
    p = pattern
    for c in pattern:
        C = c.upper()
        p = p.replace(c,"(?P<{0}>.+)".format(C),1)
        p = p.replace(c,"(?P={0})".format(C),len(pattern))
    p = '^' + p + '$'

    # check for a preliminary match
    if re.search(p,string):
        rem = re.match(p,string)
        seen = {}
        # check to ensure that no points in the pattern share the same match
        for c in pattern:
            s = rem.group(c.upper())
            # has match been seen? yes, fail, no continue
            if s in seen and seen[s] != c:
                return 0
            seen[s] = c
        # success
            return  1
    # did not hit the search, fail
    return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

@EricM

I tested your DFS solution and it seems wrong, like case:

pattern = ["a", "b", "a"], s = "patrpatrr"

The problem is that when you meet a pattern that already exists in dict and find it cannot fit the following string, you delete and try to assign it a new value. However, you haven't check this pattern with the new value for the previous times it occurs.

My idea is about providing addition dict (or merge in this dict) new value to keep track of the first time it appears and another stack to keep track of the unique pattern I meet. when "not match" occurs, I will know there is some problem with the last pattern and I pop it from the stack and modify the corresponding value in the dict, also I will start to check again at that corresponding index. If cannot be modified any more. I will pop until there is none left in the stack and then return False.

(I want to add comments but don't have enough reputation as a new user.. I haven't implement it but till now I haven't find any error in my logic. I am sorry if there is something wrong with my solution== I will try to implement it later.)

Comment: Indeed, the version I pushed was pretty much garbage.  I added Alexander Taylor's cases and yours, fixed it and cleaned it up a little.  See the updated gist.  I still prefer the regexp idea though: the regexp engine does the DFS for you, so less risk of wiriting bugs :-D

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of much better than the brute force solution: try every possible partitioning of the word (this is essentially what Jan described).

The run-time complexity is `O(n^(2m))` where `m` is the length of the pattern and `n` is the length of the string.

Here's what the code for that looks like (I made my code return the actual mapping instead of just 0 or 1. Modifying the code to return 0 or 1 is easy):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class StringBijection {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String chars = "abaac";
        String string = "johnjohnnyjohnjohncodes";
        List<String> stringBijection = getStringBijection(chars, string);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringBijection.toArray()));
    }

    public static List<String> getStringBijection(String chars, String string) {
        if (chars == null || string == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Map<Character, String> bijection = new HashMap<Character, String>();
        Deque<String> assignments = new ArrayDeque<String>();
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        boolean hasBijection = getStringBijection(chars, string, 0, 0, bijection, assignments);

        if (!hasBijection) {
            return null;
        }

        for (String result : assignments) {
            results.add(result);
        }

        return results;
    }

    private static boolean getStringBijection(String chars, String string, int charIndex, int stringIndex, Map<Character, String> bijection, Deque<String> assignments) {
        int charsLen = chars.length();
        int stringLen = string.length();

        if (charIndex == charsLen && stringIndex == stringLen) {
            return true;
        } else if (charIndex == charsLen || stringIndex == stringLen) {
            return false;
        }

        char currentChar = chars.charAt(charIndex);
        List<String> possibleWords = new ArrayList<String>();
        boolean charAlreadyAssigned = bijection.containsKey(currentChar);

        if (charAlreadyAssigned) {
            String word = bijection.get(currentChar);
            possibleWords.add(word);
        } else {
            StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = stringIndex; i < stringLen; ++i) {
                word.append(string.charAt(i));
                possibleWords.add(word.toString());
            }
        }

        for (String word : possibleWords) {
            int wordLen = word.length();
            int endIndex = stringIndex + wordLen;

            if (endIndex <= stringLen && string.substring(stringIndex, endIndex).equals(word)) {
                if (!charAlreadyAssigned) {
                    bijection.put(currentChar, word);
                }

                assignments.addLast(word);

                boolean done = getStringBijection(chars, string, charIndex + 1, stringIndex + wordLen, bijection, assignments);

                if (done) {
                    return true;
                }

                assignments.removeLast();

                if (!charAlreadyAssigned) {
                    bijection.remove(currentChar);
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a solution in C++, here is a brute force solution:
https://linzhongzl.wordpress.com/2014/11/04/repeating-pattern-match/

Answer (score 0):

Plain Brute Force, not sure if any optimization is possible here ..

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.junit.*;

public class Pattern {
   private Map<Character, String> map;
   private boolean matchInt(String pattern, String str) {
      if (pattern.length() == 0) {
         return str.length() == 0;
      }
      char pch = pattern.charAt(0);
      for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
         if (!map.containsKey(pch)) {
            String val = str.substring(0, i + 1);
            map.put(pch, val);
            if (matchInt(pattern.substring(1), str.substring(val.length()))) {
               return true;
            } else {
               map.remove(pch);
            }
         } else {
            String val = map.get(pch);
            if (!str.startsWith(val)) {
               return false;
            }
            return matchInt(pattern.substring(1), str.substring(val.length()));
         }
      }
      return false;
   }
   public boolean match(String pattern, String str) {
      map = new HashMap<Character, String>();
      return matchInt(pattern, str);
   }
   @Test
   public void test1() {
      Assert.assertTrue(match("aabb", "ABABCDCD"));
      Assert.assertTrue(match("abba", "redbluebluered"));
      Assert.assertTrue(match("abba", "asdasdasdasd"));
      Assert.assertFalse(match("aabb", "xyzabcxzyabc"));
      Assert.assertTrue(match("abba", "catdogdogcat"));
      Assert.assertTrue(match("abab", "ryry"));
      Assert.assertFalse(match("abba", " redblueredblue"));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class StringPattern{
public:
  int n, pn;
  string str;
  unordered_map<string, pair<string, int>> um;
  vector<string> p;
  bool match(string pat, string str_) {
    p.clear();
    istringstream istr(pat);
    string x;
    while(istr>>x) p.push_back(x);
    pn=p.size();
    str=str_;
    n=str.size();
    um.clear();
    return dfs(0, 0);
  }

  bool dfs(int i, int c) {
    if(i>=n) {
      if(c>=pn){
          return 1;
      }
    }
    if(c>=pn) return 0;
    for(int len=1; i+len-1<n; len++) {
      string sub=str.substr(i, len);


      if(um.count(p[c]) && um[p[c]].fi!=sub
         || um.count(sub) && um[sub].fi!=p[c]
         )
          continue;
      //cout<<"str:"<<endl;
      //cout<<p[c]<<" "<<sub<<endl;
      um[p[c]].fi=sub;
      um[p[c]].se++;
      um[sub].fi=p[c];
      um[sub].se++;
      //um[sub]=p[c];
      if(dfs(i+len, c+1)) return 1;
      um[p[c]].se--;
      if(!um[p[c]].se) um.erase(p[c]);
      um[sub].se--;
      if(!um[sub].se) um.erase(sub);
      //um.erase(sub);
    }
    return 0;
  }
};
```

My solution, as two side hashmap is needed, and also need to count the hash map counts

Answer (score 0):

### My java script solution:

```
function isMatch(pattern, str){

  var map = {}; //store the pairs of pattern and strings

  function checkMatch(pattern, str) {

    if (pattern.length == 0 && str.length == 0){
      return true;
    }
    //if the pattern or the string is empty
    if (pattern.length == 0 || str.length == 0){
      return false;
    }

    //store the next pattern
    var currentPattern = pattern.charAt(0);

    if (currentPattern in map){
        //the pattern has alredy seen, check if there is a match with the string
        if (str.length >= map[currentPattern].length  && str.startsWith(map[currentPattern])){
          //there is a match, try all other posibilities
          return checkMatch(pattern.substring(1), str.substring(map[currentPattern].length));
        } else {
          //no match, return false
          return false;
        }
    }

    //the current pattern is new, try all the posibilities of current string
    for (var i=1; i <= str.length; i++){
        var stringToCheck = str.substring(0, i);

        //store in the map
        map[currentPattern] = stringToCheck;
        //try the rest
        var match = checkMatch(pattern.substring(1), str.substring(i));
        if (match){
            //there is a match
             return true;
        } else {
           //if there is no match, delete the pair from the map
           delete map[currentPattern];
        }
    }
    return false;
  }

  return checkMatch(pattern, str);
```

}

Comment: There is an error in your code. Your check str.length >= map[currentPattern].length  && str.startsWith(map[currentPattern]) is not true. kindly review and correct the solution.

Answer (score 0):

A solution in Java I wrote (based on this [HackerRank Dropbox Challenge practice](https://www.hackerrank.com/tests/lgj8a2nd/e56e73b13b75f05a4a046cbb985bba39)).

You can play with the `DEBUG_VARIATIONS` and `DEBUG_MATCH` flags to have a better understanding of how the algorithm works.

It may be too late now, but you might want to attempt to tackle the problem at HackerRank first before reading through the proposed solutions! ;-)

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Solution {

    private static final boolean DEBUG_VARIATIONS = false;
    private static final boolean DEBUG_MATCH = true;

    static int wordpattern(final String pattern, final String input) {
        if (pattern.length() == 1) {
            return 1;
        }

        final int nWords = pattern.length();

        final List<List<String>> lists = split(input, nWords);

        for (final List<String> words : lists) {
            if (DEBUG_VARIATIONS) {
                System.out.print("-> ");
                for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.printf("%s ", words.get(i));
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

            if (matches(pattern, words)) {
                return 1;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }

    // Return every possible way to split 'input' into 'n' parts
    private static final List<List<String>> split(final String input, final int n) {
        final List<List<String>> variations = new ArrayList<>();

        // Stop recursion when n == 2
        if (n == 2) {
            for (int i = 1; i < input.length(); i++) {
                final List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
                l.add(input.substring(0, i));
                l.add(input.substring(i));
                variations.add(l);
            }
            return variations;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < input.length() - n + 1; i++) {
            final List<List<String>> result = split(input.substring(i), n - 1);
            for (List<String> l : result) {
                l.add(0, input.substring(0, i));
            }
            variations.addAll(result);
        }

        return variations;
    }

    // Return 'true' if list of words matches patterns
    private static final boolean matches(final String pattern, final List<String> words) {
        final Map<String, String> patterns = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length(); i++) {
            final String key = String.valueOf(pattern.charAt(i));
            final String value = words.get(i);

            boolean hasKey = patterns.containsKey(key);
            boolean hasValue = patterns.containsValue(value);

            if (!hasKey && !hasValue) {
                patterns.put(key, value);
            } else if (hasKey && !hasValue) {
                return false;
            } else if (!hasKey && hasValue) {
                return false;
            } else if (hasKey && hasValue) {
                if (!value.equals(patterns.get(key))) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        if (DEBUG_MATCH) {
            System.out.print("Found match! -> ");
            for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
                System.out.printf("%s ", words.get(i));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println(wordpattern("abba", "redbluebluered"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Python solution based on Java solution at: https://www.algo.monster/problems/word_pattern_ii

```
def helper(pattern, s, idxPattern, idxString, myMap, mySet):
    if (idxPattern == len(pattern)) and (idxString == len(s)):
        return True
    if (idxPattern >= len(pattern)) or (idxString >= len(s)):
        return False
    thisChar = pattern[idxPattern]
    #print ("At Char: ", thisChar, " at location: ", idxPattern)
    for idxK in range(idxString + 1, len(s) + 1):
        subString = s[idxString:idxK]
        if (thisChar not in myMap) and (subString not in mySet) :
            myMap[thisChar] = subString
            mySet.add(subString)
            # print ("Before Map {0}, Set: {1}".format(myMap, mySet))       
            if helper(pattern, s, idxPattern + 1, idxK, myMap, mySet):
                return True
            myMap.pop(thisChar)
            mySet.remove(subString)
            # print ("After Map {0}, Set: {1}".format(myMap, mySet))      
        elif (thisChar in myMap) and (myMap[thisChar] == subString):
            if helper(pattern, s, idxPattern + 1, idxK, myMap, mySet):
                return True    
      
def word_pattern_match(pattern: str, s: str) -> bool:
    # WRITE YOUR BRILLIANT CODE HERE
    print ("Pattern {0}, String {1}".format(pattern, s))
    if (len(pattern) == 0) and (len(s) == 0):
        return True
    if (len(pattern) == 0):
        return False
    myMap = dict()
    mySet = set()

    return helper(pattern, s, 0, 0, myMap, mySet)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pattern = input()
    s = input()
    res = word_pattern_match(pattern, s)
    print('true' if res else 'false')
```

Answer (score -1):

recursively check each combination.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

/**
 * Given a string and a pattern, check if the whole string is following the given pattern.
 * e.g.
 * string            pattern     return
 * redblueredblue     abab        a:red, b:blue  true
 * redbb               aba          false
 * 
 * Concept:
 * Recursively checking
 * point_pat:0 point_str:0 a:r point_pat:1 point_str:1 b:e/ed/edb...
 * point_pat:0 point_str:1 a:re point_pat:1 point_str:2 b:d/db/dbl...
 */

bool isMatch(const string &str, const string &pattern, unordered_map<char, string> &match_table, int point_str, int point_pat)
{
    if (point_pat >= pattern.size() && point_str >= str.size())
        return true;
    if (point_pat >= pattern.size() || point_str >= str.size())
        return false;

    if (match_table.count(pattern[point_pat]))
    {
        auto &match_str = match_table[pattern[point_pat]];
        if (str.substr(point_str, match_str.size()) == match_str)
            return isMatch(str, pattern, match_table, point_str + match_str.size(), point_pat + 1);
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int len = 1; len <= str.size() - point_str; ++len)
        {
            match_table[pattern[point_pat]] = str.substr(point_str, len);
            if (isMatch(str, pattern, match_table, point_str + len, point_pat + 1))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

bool isMatch(const string &str, const string &pattern)
{
    unordered_map<char, string> match_table;

    bool res = isMatch(str, pattern, match_table, 0, 0);

    for (const auto &p : match_table)
    {
        cout << p.first << " : " << p.second << "\n";
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    string str{"redblueredblue"}, pattern{"abab"};
    cout << isMatch(str, pattern) << "\n";
    cout << isMatch(str, "ab") << "\n";
    cout << isMatch(str, "ababa") << "\n";
    cout << isMatch(str, "cba") << "\n";
    cout << isMatch(str, "abcabc") << "\n";
    cout << isMatch("patrpatrr", "aba") << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Fails for input: 
abab
redblueredblue

Answer (score -2):

Depending on what patterns are given, you can answer a 'different' question (that really is the same question).

For patterns like [a b b a] determine whether or not the string is a palindrome.

For patterns like [a b a b] determine if the second half of the string equals the first half of the string.

Longer patterns like [a b c b c a], but you still break it up into smaller problems to solve. For this one, you know that the last n characters of the string should be the reverse of the first n characters. Once they stop being equal, you simply have another [b c b c] problem to check for.

Although possible, in an interview, I doubt they'd give you anything more complex than maybe 3-4 different substrings.